# OracleSolaris 11.2 -- adding driver to system, attach fails

Tags: solaris, device-driver, opensolaris

I'm learning Solaris and writing a simple driver; currently I implemented basic entry points, i.e. `_init`, `_info`, `_finit`, `*attach`, `*detach`. It compiles and links with no issues, then I copy it to `/usr/kernel/drv/amd64/` and call:

```
% add_drv mydrv
Jul   7 22:54:16 ezhost mydrv: NOTICE: mydrv: _info called
devfsadm: driver failed to attach: mydrv
Warning: Driver (mydrv) successfully added to system but failed to attach
Jul   7 22:54:16 ezhost mydrv: NOTICE: mydrv: _init called
```

Currently what I do in my _attach routine is:

ddi_get_instance
ddi_soft_state_zalloc
ddi_get_soft_state

and return DDI_SUCCESS

Not much, but probably when the drivers gets loaded in memory, the system (devfsadm) expects to creates some entries in devfs, however my driver doesn't register any character device nodes, and as result fails?

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/kernel/drv/drivername.conf` file?

Comment: Have you created a conf file so your device will attach to a `pseudo` bus?

Comment: Andrew + myaut -- I do have /usr/kernel/drv/mydrv.conf, however it is empty, I don't know what should be in there.

Comment: @Mark: Try this: `name="mydrv" parent="pseudo" instance=0;`

Comment: @myaut, thanks! I do see my device in /devices/pseudo/mydrv@0
It means in solaris, a driver needs to be attached at least to pseudo bus?

Comment: Do you see your driver listed with `dtrace -l` after it's loaded?  Using `dtrace` might give you some insight into what's happening.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for pointing at dtrace, very useful tool indeed.